# Batch: How to use an array with a variable as an index inside a for loop?

Tags: arrays, windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

My code offers a client to enter a sequence of words (until the client enters "0"), stores them in an array and then sort that array alphabetically.
I have found a way to make my code work by using an extra for loop but I'm not happy with that way to do, **do you have any alternative to that 3rd for, please?** (the one with %%h)

My issue was coming from `%%tab[!next!]%%` and my need to delay one more time, it works when I use `CALL echo` but then I don't know how to do with the if conditions and the set.

Thank you in advance.

ps: sorry about the array and for loops starting at 1 but it makes me skip 1 more goto and the struggle to calculate the loop indexes+1.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /a num=0

:newVar
set /a num+=1
set /p tab[%num%]=Write something: 
if not !tab[%num%]! == 0 goto newVar
set /a num-=1

echo.
echo Array length: %num%
echo.

set varTemp=ERROR
set /a nbTours=%num%-1

FOR /L %%v IN (1 1 %nbTours%) DO (
   echo ***********************************************
   echo.
   set /a nbComparaison=%num%-%%v
   set /a next=1

   FOR /L %%i IN (1 1 !nbComparaison!) DO  (
      set /a next=next+1
      call echo tab[%%i] = !tab[%%i]! . tab[!next!] = %%tab[!next!]%%
      FOR %%h in (!next!) do (
         if !tab[%%i]! GTR !tab[%%h]! (
         echo ________ !tab[%%i]! ^<-^> !tab[%%h]! & echo. 
         set varTemp=!tab[%%h]!
         set tab[%%h]=!tab[%%i]!
         set tab[%%i]=!varTemp!
         )
      )
   )
   echo.
)
echo ***********************************************

echo.
echo result:
FOR /L %%d IN (1 1 %num%) DO  (
   echo tab[%%d] = !tab[%%d]!
)

endlocal
pause
```

Comment: Yes, `call` cannot be used together with `if` as well as `for`, because these commands are recognised earlier than others (like also `call`), but you could use a `for` loop to avoid the need of `call`, which is what you already do: `for %%h in (!next!) do if !tab[%%i]! gtr !tab[%%h]! ( … )`…

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient way to expand delayed variables for use as in index **within a code block** is with a simple `for` loop:

```
For %%G in (!next!)Do echo(tab[%%i] = !tab[%%i]! . tab[%%G] = !tab[%%G]!
```

If multiple delayed variables are needed within a code block as index variables, a `for /f` loop can be used to expand and isolate the required tokens.

```
For /l %%i in (1 1 10) Do (
    Set /A Next=%%i+1,Previous=%%i-1
    For /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%G in ("!Pevious!;!Next!;%%i") Do (
        Echo(%%G - %%H - %%I
    )
)
```

Comment: Yes that's what I have done but I was looking to avoid the `for` trick.
Anyway thanks for the `for /f` it can really useful!

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /L %%v IN (1,1,%num%) DO IF (%%v neq %num%) FOR /L %%i IN (%%v,1,%num%) DO IF (%%v neq %%i) IF "!tab[%%v]!" gtr "!tab[%%i]!" (
 SET "vartemp=!tab[%%v]!"
 SET "tab[%%v]=!tab[%%i]!"
 SET "tab[%%i]=!vartemp!"
)
```

for each entry, except the last, for each remaining entry (those with a higher index) do the comparison and swap if required.

Puts the lowest of the remaining entries in index `%%v` until done.

Note that string comparisons need to be performed in quotes to cater for entries containing spaces and preferred syntax `set "var=value"` for string assignments to ensure trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned.

Comment: Nice one, it's another method but it saves some variables and makes it more compact.
But it's still with a `for`, I guess it's kind of compulsory in this situation.